# Is this a proper way of putting quotes in SQL query in ADO.NET

Tags: c#, ado.net

```
string query = @"INSERT INTO Uczniowie (ID, Name, Surname, Age)" + 
                "VALUES('" + textBox1.Text + "'" + 
                         ", '" + textBox2.Text + "'" + 
                         ",'" + textBox3.Text + "'" + 
                         ",'" + textBox3.Text + "'";
```

Comment: Parametrize the query

Comment: In one word: NO

Comment: Yes, there is, the proper way is not doing it, and by "it" I mean SQL concatenation. Use parameters, then you don't need quotes. Your current code is prone to SQL injection attacks and all sorts of problems. **Don't do it!**

Answer (score 2):

**NO**, it's not since it's now open to *SQL Injection* attack. Rather use a parameterized query like

```
string query = "INSERT INTO Uczniowie (ID, Name, Surname, Age) VALUES(@id, @name, @surname, @age)";
```

See MSDN documentation on [How to: Execute a Parameterized Query](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738521(v=vs.100).aspx) for more information on the same

Answer (score 1):

You should use parameters instead: [SqlCommand.Parameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx)

Could look like this

```
string commandText = "INSERT INTO Uczniowie (ID, Name, Surname, Age)" + 
                     "VALUES(@id, @name, @surname, @age)";

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection);
    command.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int);
    command.Parameters["@id"].Value = textBox1.Text;
    ...
}
```

This will avoid [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is the old syntax. You can try like this :

```
string query = "INSERT INTO dbo.regist (FirstName, Lastname, Username, Password, Age, Gender,Contact) " + 
               "VALUES (@FirstName, @Lastname, @Username, @Password, @Age, @Gender, @Contact) ";

// create connection and command
using(SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cn))
{
    // define parameters and their values
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = firstName;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Lastname", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = lastName;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Username", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = userName;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Password", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = password;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Age", SqlDbType.Int).Value = age;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Gender", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = gender;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Contact", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = contact;

    // open connection, execute INSERT, close connection
    cn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cn.Close();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

No. You can simply do this. like

```
string query = @"INSERT INTO Uczniowie (ID, Name, Surname, Age) VALUES(@id, @name, @surname, @age)";
```

And than add Parameters using sqlCmd like-

```
sqlcmd.Parameter.Add[@id].Values=textbox1.text;
```